# Unity: Increase animation speed of individual component in a blend tree?

Tags: animation, unity

I have blend tree with four different turns: a sprinting turn, running turn, walking turn, and standing turn.

I need to somehow make the angular velocity increase from sprinting down to standing, so that as the character gets slower he turns faster (otherwise it is basically unplayable).

How do I increase the angular velocity of an individual animation in the blend tree?  The usual "speed" attribute disappears when I put the animation in the blend tree...and I have not figured out how to access the blend tree substate from code yet.

Here is an image of the blend tree, and the inspector:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a speed field in each line of the blend tree.  It's the column with the clock icon.  You can use that to adjust the speed of each animation.

You can see it in the last image on this page: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html

Comment: Lol, I had hardcoded a speed increase corresponding to the blend in the script.   Thank you--that makes it much easier.